# Jars having same package structure and class

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, tomcat7

**Problem -** I have an issue with two jars in my web application which I am developing using Eclipse IDE of Mars version and hosting it on apache tomcat 7.0 web server -

1. hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final
2. com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_7.0.0

Both of them have same package structure and and same class -

> javax.persistence.CascadeType

This package and class is a ENUM type declaration which was being used from first jar. And I have recently added the second jar which is also mandatory as a dependency for a third party jar for authentication and authorization for my application. Once the second jar is added, I have got this issue where the package intended to be used from first jar is being picked up from the second jar.

The Enumeration value `CascadeType.DETACH` was being used from first jar file in the application and this ENUM value is not defined in its counterpart in the second jar. Hence this issue is being faced.

**Things I have already tried and no result -**

1. Tried to remove the above conflicting package from the second jar and added to the library. Then this jar was not being picked up at run time and I was getting noclassdeffound error for the class - com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.GeneratedService even after this class is visible inside the second jar itself in classpath.
2. Instead of CascadeType.DETACH, I tried to use some other ENUM value of the second jar itself and let the compiler ignore first jar. Then was getting the noclassdeffound error for the class - com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.GeneratedService which is still inside the second jar.
3. Out of suggestions I got from stack overflow itself, traversed to `Right click on project -> build path -> configure build path -> Order and export` to set priority for jars. But at this option, only priority can be set within library sets like WEBAPP libraries, JDK libraries or externally configured libraries but not within individual jars inside a set of libraries. But my both libraries were inside WEBAPP libraries set itself and hence could not set the priority of those jars using this option. As another trial, I removed the second jar from the WEBAPP libraries and configured as an external library instead and set its priority lower than WEBAPP libraries which contained my first jar. Still was getting the same issue- noclassdeffound error for the class - com.ibm.ws.webservices.multiprotocol.GeneratedService which is still inside the second jar.
4. Some suggestions from stack overflow were setting dependencies in maven pom xml. This will not be applicable to my application as I am not running it through maven but just running it on tomcat web server.

Please suggest a way forward to resolve this issue. Please note that this application is targeted for Websphere server at environment level. Tomcat server is being used at the local setup itself. Please suggest keeping this in mind. I also tried installing websphere server for local setup as well but could not do it as commercial servers are not allowed to be installed inside our organization.

Comment: Time to learn about ClassLoader's. There may be a variety of options available depending on your overall packaging of your system. And it depends on the level of inter-dependencies in your system. But short version would be to isolate the authentication code, set up a custom ClassLoader for that block of code, and explicitly reference the IBM thinclient from that ClassLoader and nowhere else.

Comment: ClassLoaders also is an option which I have already tried, but forgot to mention. But while looking for this option in google. I was getting some suggestions as class loaders cannot guarantee a long term solution. Also I am targeting to deploy it on Websphere at environment level. Will that not be a problem? I mean will that work across the servers also?

Comment: Then perhaps your easiest approach is to also switch to using the Websphere JPA client libraries. I wouldn't do that if you were deploying to Tomcat for ops, but if your end solution is Websphere, then why not also use Websphere JPA entirely?